# What can I do to avoid a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, client

I am trying to authenticate user by sending a key and a random number from the client to the server.

My code is not displaying me the response from the client. I am getting a Null Pointer Exception when I execute my code as below.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Client 

{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {

        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("enter the key value");
        int key=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        double random=Math.random()*50;
        System.out.println(random);
        int response=key%((int)random);
        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println("Authentication begins");
        Socket echoSocket = new Socket("localhost", 2000);
        FileOutputStream fout=null;
        DataOutputStream clientout=null;
        clientout.writeDouble(random);
        clientout.writeInt(key);
        clientout.writeInt(response);    
        fout.flush();
        System.out.println("client is"+response);
        echoSocket.close();

    }
}

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Server
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        int response2;
        double random2;
        int key2;
        FileInputStream fin=null;
        DataInputStream clientin=null;
        ServerSocket s= new ServerSocket(2000);
        Socket echoSocket=s.accept();
        random2=clientin.readDouble();
        key2=clientin.readInt();
        response2=clientin.readInt();
        response2=key2%((int)random2);
        System.out.println("server is"+response2);
        s.close();
        echoSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It's impossible to read that way.

Comment: @JB Nizet : ohh sorry I will do it

Comment: @Parth: "Indenting properly" does not mean to have everything with the same indentation. Your Editor/IDE should have a function to indent code, use this before copying. (I did it now for you.)

Comment: @Paulo Ebermann : OK will do it henceforth ..Thanks a lot !! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canned steps for solving most `NullPointerException`s:

1. Read the stack trace to determine what line of code throws the NPE
2. Put a breakpoint at that line of code
3. Using the debugger, when the breakpoint is hit, gigure out what object reference in that line is `null`
4. Figure out why that reference is `null` (this is the only actual hard part so far)
5. Fix the underlying cause (also potentially difficult)

Comment: What to u mean by inserting a break point and reading the stack trace ?

Comment: Typically, when you see an exception such as a `NullPointerException` in the console, you see a [stack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) printed out. This will tell you what line of code the exception was thrown by. As for breakpoints - are you using any sort of IDE, like Eclipse, NetBeans, or IntelliJ? They all have integrated debuggers which you can use to  debug your code. Here is a tutorial which explains how to use Eclipse's debugger: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: I have written my code in notepad and I have used jdk 1.6 to run my code. I guess something is wrong with client side code this line "clientout.writeDouble(random)...i guess DataOutputStream should be initialized to a value ..am i right ?

Comment: Yes, you're right, but the stack trace tells it to you : java.lang.NullPointerException **at Client.java:22** where 22 is the number of the line where the exception is thrown.

Comment: clientout should be an OutputStream to the server: clientout = new DataOutputStream(echoSocket.getOutputStream()). You don't need any FileOutputStream since you don't write anything to a file. Read the Java tutorial about sockets: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: and clientin=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream()) rite ?

Comment: Also feel free to omit the debugger steps and simply use your brain. The stack trace gives the exact line of the exception. You know the variable is null. So start thinking, "how would that happen?"

Comment: @Kevin I recommend the debugger primarily because it is sometimes unclear from the stack trace precisely which object reference on a given line is null.