# Java NullPointerException on createStatement

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do to avoid a NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132614/what-can-i-do-to-avoid-a-nullpointerexception)

I'm developing an application for a restaurant. The error occurs when I try to initialize a certain class. Here is the code.

```
public class DbItem {

private static Connection conn = null;

static {
    conn = DBConnection.connect();
}
public static ArrayList<Item> fetchAll() {
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "select * from itens";
    try {
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()) {
            items.add(new Item(rs.getString("nome"), rs.getString("descricao"), rs.getFloat("preco")));
        }
        return items;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbItem.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

The connection is taken from this class

```
public class DBConnection {

private static Connection conn;

public static Connection connect() {
    if(conn == null) {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String dbName = "restaurante_comandas_jonnathan";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "root";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
            System.out.println("Connected to " + dbName + " with " + userName);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, conn == null);
            return conn;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

I tried debugging using popup boxes. I checked if the connection was null right before the return command, and found out is was not. Then, I checked after the call on the first script, and found out it was, indeed, null. Now, how can an object be null right after the retrieving if it wasn't before the return?

Edit:

Here it is. The stack trace

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at model.data.DbItem.fetchAll(DbItem.java:48)
at model.Item.getAll(Item.java:76)
at view.PedidoForm.<init>(PedidoForm.java:22)
at view.Login$2.run(Login.java:99)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: have you tried attaching with a debugger?  paste your stack trace...

Comment: I actually don't know how to use a debugger. I've used plain text editor for most of my life.

Comment: Now might be the time to invest some effort and learn.  You can download IntelliJ IDE for free and debug your code.  Is it a webapp or a plain java program?

Comment: Plain Java. I'm using Netbeans and I really think the conclusions I'm getting from the debugger will be the same I got with warnings and popup boxes in this case.

Comment: Try this: Total shot in the dark.  At the end of connect, instead of returning null, return conn.  Then in your fetchAll method instead of calling connect in the static initializer, call it in fetchAll directly as the first statement in your try block

Comment: Thanks, Amir. I got all that mixed out. How can we manage this to be an acceptable answer?

Comment: @PatrickVillela That is a false belief. Sorry. With a debugger attached - IntelliJ or Eclispe or other - it will be possible to *break at the exception* and inspect the exact values. If value(s) are not as expected, breakpoints can be set and the program can be walked and expressions can be monitored as needed. That is, unlike "guessing", it can be systematically verified. Either some assumptions are wrong or the JVM is wrong. Pick one.

Comment: You were relying on a very specific ordering for class load events is my guess - but you would know for sure if you attached with the debugger.

Comment: You're right. I should have begun using it a long time before. Thank you all.

Comment: (I'm not really trying to be mean: It just breaks my heart when stuff is being done the hard way .. I've already BTDT. Your time is more valuable.)

Comment: @PatrickVillela, not sure if you already have a solution yet. Quick questions - what is line 48 in DBItem? Also, have you checked if there's a spelling error in your SQL (itens) that may be causing this error? On a side note, you should also close the statement and resultset once processed. Actually, there shouldnt be any reason you use JDBC directly, you could just do a ORM

Comment: @PatrickVillela, sorry just noticed, why do have all that static stuff ? btw the last line in DBConnection should return conn and not null. May be thats what the error is. But this design is very prone to errors. What if there's a network blip and the connection you are storing in static var gets stale? I suggest getting rid of the statics and use a connection pool instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code and made some changes. Please try this

```
public class DBConnection {

private static Connection conn;

public static Connection connect() {
    if(conn == null) {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "restaurante_comandas_jonnathan";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "root";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
        System.out.println("Connected to " + dbName + " with " + userName);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, conn == null);            
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return conn;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure I can accept this answer, since Amir was the one that pointed it to me first.